# Vertically centering text in a container when using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have been struggling for the last couple of days trying to figure out how to properly center text vertically. There is also a full-width background image.

I would like the text to stay centered no matter what height the enclosing container is.

Here is the code I have so far:

**HTML:**

```
<header class="thank-you">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="thank-you-message">
          <h1>Thank you</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thank-you {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background: #000000;
  height: 500px;
}
.thank-you-message h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `translate`:

```
h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4ehmpdq5/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add

```
line-height:500px;
vertical-align:middle;
```

to your css:

```
.thank-you {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background: #000000;
  height: 500px;
    line-height:500px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

See this

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mou6y875/)

Comment: This solution isn't very elegant when you have multiple lines of text.

Answer (score 1):

The most versatile solution is using flexbox:

```
.thank-you-message{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```